# How do I deal with rich content with the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework

I'm not sure how to deal with rich content. Some examples that I want to return are a list of hyperlinks or a/some image thumbnails. How do I do this? I tried formatting my text as HTML and that crashed the Bot Emulator and caused the Web Chat client to just display encoded HTML.

Is there a secret to this or some documentation explaining this?

Comment: Yes, there is documentation, but good luck in finding the bit that tells you actually how to implement it. I found this: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html which shows you what the markdowns are but does NOT show you how to implement it into your code. Microsoft documentation is unhelpful and shit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Markdown. Bot Framework converts Markdown to the rich native formats for each channel.

Some channels support even richer content via the ChannelData field (for example, you can send Slack Cards through our Slack channel in the ChannelData field) but all of our channels do the right thing for that channel if you send Markdown.

Edit: docs here: http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/#the-text-property-is-markdown

Comment: Please update your answer to contain examples, because the contents of that link has changed. (This is why only including a link with no examples is generally discouraged).

Comment: This makes it a real pain to deal with multiline content that includes < > etc. You have to split each line, surround it with backticks, and send two EOL characters for each line. It would be much nicer if we could post <![CDATA[]]> elements; at least try to support the "github flavoured" markdown with multiline preformatted (3 backticks).

Comment: Yep, need an example! The documentation is absolutely horrific - some of the worst around. Doesn't provide any real examples and just generally unhelpful. I genuinely think the guys at Microsoft don't even know themselves.

Answer (score 7):

You may find github's link helpful:

https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

```
Style               Markdown    Description Example
Bold                **text**    make the text bold  
Italic              *text*      make the text italic    
Header1-5           # H1        Mark a line as a header 
Strikethrough       ~~text~~    make the text strikethrough 
Hr                  ---         insert a horizontal rule    
Unordered list      *           Make an unordered list item 
Ordered list        1.          Make an ordered list item starting at 1 
Pre                 `text`      Preformatted text(can be inline)    
Block quote         > text      quote a section of text 

link               [bing](http://bing.com)  
image link         ![duck](http://aka.ms/Fo983c)
```

Note the channels will vary as to what subset of markdown they support.

Comment: +1, this was more helpful (since the contents were still there) -- I hadn't realized "markdown" was a standard thing, so thanks for that. -- But please do update your answer to include examples, and not just a link (answering with just a link is generally discouraged).

Answer (score 1):

You may find this thread useful with some examples and Yes MD is the answer.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2289

so say if you want to do an unordered list.

```
Unordered list\r\n\r\n* An item\r\n* Another item\r\n* Yet another item\r\n* And there\'s more...\r\n\r\n
```

Unordered list

- An item
- Another item
- And there\'s more...

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/channeldata
example attachment https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments
you have to change source and twist attachment in below code.
I am able to deal with rich document in slack 
refer this slack example with rich content with Microsoft bot framework

```
enter code here
bot.dialog('/', function (session) {

    session.send('Looking into your upcoming flights to see if you check-in on any of those...');
    var card =  {
  slack: {
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#36a64f",
            "pretext": "Optional text that appears above the attachment block",
            "author_name": "Bobby Tables",
            "author_link": "http://flickr.com/bobby/",
            "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
            "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Priority",
                    "value": "High",
                    "short": false
                }
            ],
            "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
            "footer": "Slack API",
            "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
            "ts": 123456789
        }
    ]
}
}
var msg = new builder.Message(session).sourceEvent(card);
session.send(msg);
});
```